# Are these small bubbles on the base of the toilet tank normal?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I just replaced the fill valve and flapper in my toilet. Everything looks fine but after a while I see that there are bubbles that accumulate around the flapper and the rubber washers in the toilet tank.

There's no dicernable leak. Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's fine. That's just air dissolved in the water forming on the [nucleation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation) points of the rubber.

[image]